# wxpython SearchCtrl two events triggered

Tags: python, events, wxpython

I am using a SearchCtrl with a dropdown menu and I'm having some trouble with the events. When I click the little arrow [image: screenshot searchctrl] next to the search button, the `EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN` is triggered, which is not what I want. I only want the `EVT_MENU_RANGE` to be triggered after I clicked an item, and not also the `EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN` before i click it.

```
self.search_ctrl = wx.SearchCtrl(self.panel_1, -1,
                                 style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
self.search_menu = wx.Menu()
self.search_items = {"text1":"value1", "text2":"value2"}
for txt in self.search_items:
    self.search_menu.Append(-1, txt)
self.search_ctrl.SetMenu(self.search_menu)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN, self.search, self.search_ctrl)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_RANGE, self.onSearchMenu)
```

Although I should probably add id's to the menu bind, this isn't causing the problem. The code works as expected when I comment out the search button bind.

**UPDATE**
Apparently this isn't a problem, but a 'feature' of the searchctrl. I tried the wxpython demo and the menu also showed up if I just clicked the search button, and not the arrow. It is apparently one button, instead of the two i thought it was.
Is there a way to accomplish my original request? Do i have to manually modify a textctrl, or is there an other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the examples I've seen suggest you need to specify a range of IDs when you call your menu bind.

Maybe by default it binds to something unexpected... ?

**Edit** - In light of your update, it seems likely that you're going to need to make a custom control to me..

Comment: no, the menu bind isn't the problem. When i commented out the search button bind the code worked as expected.

Comment: What happens if you try `self.search_ctrl.bind` instead of `self.Bind`? This example seems to suggest you should be using the control's bind function: http://nullege.com/codes/search/wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN

Comment: According to one article, the two are essentially the same unless something elsewhere in the event processing heirarchy is doing something odd: http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've bumped into this before and I think if you check the control id's sending the events you'll see one wx.EVT_MENU_RANGE coming from the search button ID instead of the menu item IDs

Comment: Try assigning IDs to each of the controls and menu items and then bind to those specific IDs. As it stands, they're all bound to the same -1 ID...

Comment: i tried all of your suggestions but it didn't work. Then had the genius idea to check the demo again. To see what I found out, please see the updated question.